# Pure Data Vanilla: Random float number generator

Tags: puredata

I was wondering if it's possible to have a random object that generates floating point numbers within a certain range in Pure Data Vanilla.

For example something that generates a float between 0.0 and 1.0?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to post this on DSP ?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to consider investigating the tag 'randomF'.

Comment: Thanks @Mark that could be an option, but randomF is provided as part of Pd Externals, I was wondering if there is something similar in Pd Vanilla. https://puredata.info/docs/ListOfPdExternals/

Comment: https://puredata.info/docs/Deken might help bring additional libraries into vanilla.

Answer (score 0):

You could always generate a random number between 0 and 99 (then add 1 to the result to avoid 0) and then divide that number by 100.
ex. 50/100 = 0.5

Comment: the issue with this solution is that there is no mention of the pure data objects that could be used for "generating a random number". the [/ ] object can be used to divide the number. so "something" -> [+ 1] -> [/ 100]  but the something is what's missing here from this being an answer.